# ffmpeg was not found on your system in Azure service fabric application

Tags: asp.net-core, ffmpeg, azure-service-fabric, file-not-found

I have a stateless service fabric application, which uses ffmpeg.exe to convert video files. ffmpeg.exe is added to the project and it's properties set to Content & Copy always. When I install the app on Azure VM (Service Fabric 5 node cluster), it has been deployed to D:\SvcFab\_App\Sample_App1\Sample.Code.1.0.0. (D drive is temp storage on Azure VM). When ever I try to convert a video file, I am getting ffmpeg.exe was not found on your system exception. I am able to convert files in development environment and on on-prem server without any exception.

I tried to access ffmpeg.exe using Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), “ffmpeg.exe”) and Path.Combine(FabricRuntime.GetActivationContext().GetCodePackageObject(“Code”).Path, “ffmpeg.exe”)

Answer (score 0):

- `ffmpeg` won't work unless you have it preinstalled on the vm you are using.
- Once installed it will work without even needing to place the `ffmpeg.exe` with the source code.
- If you are using a Linux VM then installation can be done using package manager.

Here I have yum as a package manager.

```
yum install ffmpeg
```

- if you are using a windows VM then you have to first upload the entire folder which you have downloaded from the ffmpeg website and then you have to set the address of the `bin`  folder to the  `path` environment variable.
- This can be achieved in command line using the following command

```
$Env:PATH += ";<Path to you bin folder>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, in my case, I developed a REST API with Node JS and I had to convert webm to mp4. However, to install ffmpeg I had to use th SSH console  that provide Azure platform. The virtual machine use debian system, so I runned the follow commands lines:

```bash
apt-get update
apt-get install ffmpeg -y
```

The problem is that the directory is out the home directory, so isn't persist.